How can I set up VSCode to recognize premake5's global functions and not warn me about them?
I have a project at work that uses premake5 for configuration. In VSCode, I have the sumneko.lua extension installed. Premake defines a large number of functions and other properties that we use, however all of our premake5.lua files appear with warning underlines beneath anything defined in premake (normal lua standard library stuff seems fine).
How can I configure our VSCode project such that we get better language server results (and no warnings) for the premake-defined stuff?

It seems you have to provide a definition-file.

I suggest to go to both repos and add a feature request.
